# how to handle the popups from frank-cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, frank

I have this test case

Feature: Login to the app
Scenario: Successful login

```
     Given ....................
     When ....................  
     And A popup menu is displayed with the with the message "Please enter ......"
     Then I press the "Enter" button
```

The first two steps have been resolved but the last 2 not at all because I have found how to handle the popups which comes from the iphone app.

any idea?

I am using frank-cucumber

Comment: When you have the popup open, you should run `frank inspect` to inspect the view hierarchy of your app. I think you'll find that the button in your popup is not a standard UIButton. Once you figure out what it is, you'll need to craft a view selector to target it. http://www.testingwithfrank.com/selector_syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the steps for alerts provided here:
https://github.com/moredip/Frank/blob/master/gem/lib/frank-cucumber/core_frank_steps.rb

Also note that there are some issues with Frank and iOS7 to touch alerts:
https://github.com/moredip/Frank/issues/234